# Is there any reasonable SSDP or DIDL Lib for java/groovy/python?

Tags: java, python, groovy, upnp

For a future project I am looking for a library to handle SSDP communication and messages in DIDL-Lite xml dialect. Is there any reasonable implementation of java, groovy or python?

I don't like to use implementations of existing UPnP stacks like cybergarage or the frauenhofer UPnP stack because they are highly depending on these stacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://teleal.org/projects/cling

Open Source DLNA/UPnP stack, libraries, and tools for Java and Android developers

Cling is very modular, so you could only use its SSDP functionality. You can integrate it with your existing code at any level (data transport, protocol execution, etc).

The Cling Support package contains a JAXB-based DIDL parser for UPnP A/V service implementors that can be used standalone.

Comment: could we have a ssdp example